# Wrong unit price in MercadoPago?

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I'm implementing MercadoPago for my customer, using API and PHP SDK.

While I try to setup a payment process (using redirect URL) through a checkout/preferences, I send an item with an unit price at $40,34:

```
[items] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => My item
                [quantity] => 1
                [unit_price] => 40.34
                [currency_id] => USD
            )

    )
```

But when redirection is done to MercadoPago, I then have $125,601 displayed instead of $40,34. So I cannot tell MercadoPago to use the good amount!

How to fix my API call to Mercado to get the right unit price on payment process?

Comment: An advice: Try post this issue in StackOverflow in Portuguese. You will get more answers.

Comment: Sorry I don't speak Portuguese, only French or English ;)

Comment: Did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$preference_data = array(
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "id" => "Code",
            "title" => "Title of what you are paying for",
            "currency_id" => "ARS",
            "description" => "Description",
            "category_id" => "Category",
            "quantity" => 1,
            "unit_price" => 40.34
        )
    )
)
```

I think that it will help you!